# How to implement DiAL Protocol in WinJS?

Tags: winjs, win-universal-app, chromecast

I have tried this

```
var dialDevicePicker = new Windows.Media.DialProtocol.DialDevicePicker();

var rect = {
  width:200,
  height:200,
  x:0,
  y:0
}

dialDevicePicker.show(rect);
```

Finally I got a popup searching for devices, but a message in it saying disconnect first. 
I have searched [universal samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicMediaCasting) in [GitHUB](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicMediaCasting). But, found only csharp example and not in Javascript.

Can some one help me in implementing Dial Protocol for casting videos from my app to ChromeCast?

I have added Image for reference

[image]